# How to retrieve a list of authenticated users on IIS app?

Tags: c#, iis, authentication

How can I retrieve a list of currently authenticated users of an IIS app pool? Windows authentication is used.

Comment: I'm using C# and MVC 5.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these methods can help you:
System.Web.Security.Membership.GetAllUsers
System.Web.Security.Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline

Answer (score -1):

You can get loged in user in the asp.net site by

```
string name = Context.User.Identity.Name.Tostring()
```

Comment: I need to get all users that are logged in, not only the current user.